# SSRS Display Multi Select Parameters are part of report Output

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008-r2, multi-select

I have a dropdown parameter that comes from a separate SQL procedure. It returns 3 strings like this `ABC, XYZ, JKL`. The parameter is mandatory, but the user can select 1 or 2 or all three of the values.

I need the report to display what the user selects.
For example if they select ABC and JKL I need the report to display `"Shows Report: ABC, JKL.`

I have the following code

`="Shows Report. Hall: "  & iif(isnothing(Parameters!hall.Value(0) = true),"", Parameters!hall.Value(0) & ", ") & iif(isnothing(Parameters!hall.Value(1) = true),"", Parameters!hall.Value(1) & ", ") & iif(isnothing(Parameters!hall.Value(2) = true),"", Parameters!hall.Value(2) ) & "."`

However when the report runs I get an #error every time it runs.
The report does work if my code looks like this

`="Shows Report. Hall: "   & Parameters!hall.Value(0)  & Parameters!hall.Value(1)   & Parameters!hall.Value(2)`  
But this only works if I select all three parameters, not 1 or 2 of them. This also doesn't give me any formatting. I could add "," in between but I only want them to display if there are more then one value.

Please advise on any suggestions to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a multi select parameter, why not just use this

```
="Shows Report. Hall: " + join(Parameters!hall.Value,", ")
```

Comment: thank you. This is great and totally worked. Thank you so much. I will have to read more about the join function to see what it is actually doing.